# Issue with mailto link in email address containing ampersand?

Tags: html, mailto

I have a mailto link like that  `<a href="mailto:a&b_admin@xyz.com" >`  it displays correctly on html but when we click on the link the outlook just shows a in the to address. Has anyone faced the same problem please suggest.

Comment: An ampersand is not a valid character in an E-Mail address, is it? (Edit: oh indeed, [it is.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Valid_email_addresses)) I guess percent encoding is your friend then

Comment: And `mailto` is very old. 90% of the visiters of your site use not their system mail, but mailservices as gmail. A link to the contactform is much userfriendly

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding) the string is required for IE and I assume will work across browsers. From 
[this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Windows Internet Explorer 7 and later. You must percent-encode all URL-reserved characters within a mailto: address. For example, the number sign (#) is used as a fragment identifier in URLs. When processing an address such as some#one@example.com, Internet Explorer copies only the portion up to the number sign into the mail client; the fragment portion including the number sign is ignored. This behavior is by design.

So you need

```
 <a href="mailto:a%26b_admin%40xyz.com">
```

As said, I expect a percent encoded address will work in all browsers, but I don't know for sure. I can confirm it works with Chrome and Thunderbird.

Comment: This line of JavaScript will convert ampersands so you don't have to do it by hand: `var emailFriendlyUrl = currentUrl.replace(/&/g, '%26');`.

Comment: I my case (bookmarklet creating and opening a mailto link in Chrome) I didn't only have to encode only ampersand, but also the percent sign in front of it, which I just learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587424/outlook-handling-of-quoted-url-parameters-in-mailto-link) which lead me to ``.replace('&', '%2526')``

Comment: Florian's comment solved a problem I've wrestled with for a long time.
The '%2526' works, where '%26' never did.

Comment: @birchy Note that `%2526` is a double encoded `&`. encode("&") = "%26", encode("%26") = "%2526". So you may be decoding twice instead of just once.