# Issues with using an email address containing an ampersand (&) via a webmail Service

Tags: php, html

This is a related problem to "Issue with mailto link in email address containing ampersand?" ([Issue with mailto link in email address containing ampersand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498225/issue-with-mailto-link-in-email-address-containing-ampersand))

What about in the case of entering an "&" directly into the "To:" line of a webmail based program (such as Optus Webmail)?

Let's keep with the same example as using in the related issue: a&b_admin@xyz.com

I have tried a%26b_admin@xyz.com with no success. I get the error message: "You must give a non-empty value for field 'emailTo'."

Is it the web browser or the underlying script parser (for what ever language PHP, XHTML, Java etc the page/application is written in) that would be causing my issue?

Comment: `urldecode()` maybe helps you

Comment: I think this question is off topic for stackoverflow. Anyway, although according to RFC 2822 it is possible to have a lot of special characters in an email address, a lot of parsers will reject them as invalid. For example `"John & Gate"@example.com` would be a valid email address.