# Allow '&' Character in mailto href links

Tags: javascript, php, html, href, mailto

I have an email `mailto` href link, and when I use a `&` character in the subject, this prevents any code rendering after this ampersand in the email subject line. i.e. `Oil & Gas`, just shows as `Oil`.

Under normal conditions I would just change the `&` to the word `and`, but the subject line is dynamically generated via post titles in Wordpress.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the subject line breaking, or in other words how I can get the `&` to show as a text character?

A stripped out version of the code is below:

```
<a href="mailto:joe@example.com?subject=Oil&Gas">Apply</a>
```

Although in the HTML of the site this is pulled in using:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $author_email;?>?subject=<?php the_title(); ?>">Apply</a>
```

Any help or ideas would be fabulous and I'm not sure if this will be html, php or Javascript solution?

Comment: URLEncode on the PHP side.

Comment: Related: [Issue with mailto link in email address containing ampersand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498225/issue-with-mailto-link-in-email-address-containing-ampersand)

Comment: I retracted my duplicate vote as the other post has no reference to PHP.

Comment: no one uses mailto links any more, spam bots harvest addresses that way. create a form and mail that

Comment: @nogad Valid concern, but not to imply that `mailto` links are obsolete. This could be for a non-public-facing site where harvesting is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape the string so it's safe to use, using the `urlencode` function, like so:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $author_email;?>?subject=<?php echo urlencode(the_title()); ?>">Apply</a>
```

[urlencode PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) the title.

```
<?php
$title = "Gas&Oil";
?>
<a href="mailto:a@mail.com?subject=<?= urlencode($title); ?>">Apply</a>
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hBf0U)

Also, since [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) echos the title by default you need to use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/), otherwise `urlencode()` will have no effect. You can see this simulated here:

```
<?php
function the_title() {
    echo "Gas & Oil";
}
function get_the_title() {
    return "Gas & Oil";
}
?>
<a href="mailto:a@mail.com?subject=<?=urlencode(the_title()); ?>">Apply</a><br> <!-- doesn't work -->
<a href="mailto:a@mail.com?subject=<?=urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>">Apply</a> <!-- works -->
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kFu1v)

However, this will encode the whole title, changing other characters that you don't necessarily need encoded. So, to avoid this, only replace `&` for `%26`:

```
<a href="mailto:a@mail.com?subject=<?=str_replace("&", "%26", the_title()); ?>">Apply</a><br> <!-- doesn't work -->
<a href="mailto:a@mail.com?subject=<?=str_replace("&", "%26", get_the_title()); ?>">Apply</a> <!-- works -->
```

Comment: Doing it this way just adds loads of unwanted string characters in the subject line. 
The subject line of the email for 'Oil & Gas Arbitration Partner' now reads: Oil+&#038;+Gas+Arbitration+Partner

Comment: Then just replace `&` for `%26` to keep your other characters. See edit.

Comment: That nearly works, I only get the random #038; in the subject now? It reads –
Oil &#038; Gas Arbitration Partner –
How will I remove that #038;  I do appreciate your help thus far.

Comment: Hm, that seems to be related to your mail client. What are you using?

Comment: I use Thunderbird

Comment: Can you show me the output of `var_dump(the_title()); var_dump(str_replace("&", "%26", get_the_title()));` please

Comment: This is what was outputted onto the page:  Oil & Gas Arbitration PartnerNULL string(36) "Oil %26#038; Gas Arbitration Partner"

Comment: Sorry, for the first one use `var_dump(get_the_title());` as well

Comment: It looks like it returns the same: Oil & Gas Arbitration PartnerNULL string(36) "Oil %26#038; Gas Arbitration Partner"

Comment: It looks like `get_the_title()` does some encoding on its own. Try this: `str_replace("&", "%26", html_entity_decode(get_the_title()));`

Comment: No, that returns an empty subject line.

Comment: Really? You aaded `html_entity_decode()` and now it's empty? It should look like this: `<a href="mailto:a@mail.com?subject=<?=str_replace("&", "%26", html_entity_decode(get_the_title())); ?>">Apply</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the ampersand with either "%26" or "&" :

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $author_email;?>?subject=<?php str_replace('&', '%26', the_title()); ?>">Apply</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $author_email;?>?subject=<?php echo str_replace('&amp;','%26',rawurlencode(htmlspecialchars_decode(the_title()))); ?>">Apply</a>
```

Use PHP combination: `str_replace('&amp;','%26',rawurlencode(htmlspecialchars_decode(the_title())));`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the & character needs to be escaped in a URL as & is treated as a control character.

You can escape it by using HTML encoding. For example, `&amp;` is a `&` character, and `&nbsp` is a non-breaking space.

In JavaScript you can use "encodeURIComponent" for subject and body. Then it will show all special characters in email.

Example:

```
    const emailRequest = {
            to: "abc@xyz.com",
            cc: "abc@xyz.com",
            subject: "Email Request - for <CompanyName>",
            body: `Hi All, \r\n \r\n This is my company <CompanyName> 
            \r\n Thanks
        }

    const subject = encodeURIComponent(emailRequest.subject.replace("<CompanyName>",'ABC & ** Company'));
    const body = encodeURIComponent(emailRequest.body .replace("<CompanyName>", 'ABC & ** Company'));

    window.location.href = (`mailto:${emailRequest.to}?cc=${emailRequest.cc}&subject=${subject}&body=${body}`);
```